# Синхронизация прокрутки высоты блока с шириной блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

есть 2 дива:

- один в ширину `0%`
- другой в высоту `2000+ px`

Нужно синхронизировать их, по мере прокрутки второго дива

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (window.pageYOffset >= $('.article').offset().top) {
    }
})
```

Проверка на вхождение есть , как дальше мне синхронизировать процент ширины первого дива с высотой и нынешней прокруткой второго

Comment: Я пришел сюда помогать, а не ребусы решать... Поясните внятно, чего вы изволите желать

Comment: есть 2 дива , один в ширину 0%
другой в высоту 2000+ px
мне нужно синхронизировать их по мере прокрутки второго дива
$(window).scroll(function () {
     if (window.pageYOffset >= $('.article').offset().top) {
  }
})
Проверка на вхождение есть , как дальше мне синхронизировать процент ширины первого дива с высотой и нынешней прокруткой второго

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK это следует писать в самом вопросе, а не в комментариях к нему. [ask]

Comment: @Sublihim это было уточнение , а не сам вопрос

Comment: @MoJlo4HuK [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Описано непонятно, но предположу что как-то так:

```js
$(document).on('scroll', onScroll);

function onScroll()
{
  var width,
      scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
      firstBlock = $('.block-1'),
      secondBlock = $('.block-2'),
      secondBlockHeight = secondBlock.innerHeight(),
      secondBlockTop = secondBlock.offset().top;
      
  if(scroll >= secondBlockTop){
    width = (scroll - secondBlockTop) / secondBlockHeight * 100;
  } else if (scroll < secondBlockTop){
    width = 0;
  } else if(scroll >= secondBlockTop + secondBlockHeight) {
    width = 100;
  }
  
  firstBlock.css({ width: width + '%' });
}
```

```css
.block-1 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red
}

.block-2 {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 100px 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-1"></div>
<div class="block-2"></div>
```

Comment: ну либо для любителей мимификации можно убрать условия, оставить только: width = (scroll - secondBlockTop) / secondBlockHeight * 100; а стиль применять так: firstBlock.css({ width: width < 0 ? 0 : (width > 100 ? 100 : width) + '%' });